# Pixel-Sized Gap Between Inner and Outer Div

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is this a rendering bug in Chrome?

Using Google Chrome 107.0.5304.32 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

```css
.meters {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4rem 1fr 3rem;
  grid-auto-rows: 1.3rem;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}
.meter {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 3px black;
}
.fill {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="meters">
  <p>0 Sterne</p>
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="fill" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>27%</p>
  <p>1 Sterne</p>
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="fill" style="width: 10.989%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>11%</p>
  <p>2 Sterne</p>
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="fill" style="width: 32.4176%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>32%</p>
  <p>3 Sterne</p>
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="fill" style="width: 11.5385%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>12%</p>
  <p>4 Sterne</p>
  <div class="meter">
    <div class="fill" style="width: 17.5824%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>18%</p>
</div>
```

I see white around the blue divs:

[image]

If I set the border to `4px` or more, the white is gone.  For `1px`, it also works fine.  With `2px` I see only white at the bottom and with `3px` white on top and bottom.

Amaury Hanser in the comments mentioned zoom, so I checked and when zooming in to 110%, the white also disappears.

I even tried setting `overflow: hidden;` on `.meter` and `height: 150%;` on `fill`, so I can see in the inspector that the fill is larger than the container, but it still shows the white border:

[image]

Comment: Are you zoomed in? I don't have any issue if I'm at 100% zoom level, but I do when I zoom. It's probably a sub pixel rendering issue.

Comment: Nope, no zoom!  I will add browser details in the post.  But funny that you mention it, when I zoom to 110%, I see no white as well.  What's the best way to solve this in CSS?

Comment: I'm going to guess it comes from the browser rendering engine rounding down when the it ends up with fractions of pixels.

Comment: OK, So I tried setting the height of `.fill` to `150%` and `.meter` to `overflow: hidden;` but it's still there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not sure what is wrong but you can use outline instead

```css
 .meters {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 4rem 1fr 3rem;
            grid-auto-rows: 1.3rem;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 0.8rem;
          }
          .meter {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            outline: 3px solid black !important;
          }
          .fill {
            background: blue;
          }
```

```html
 <div class="meters">
        <p>0 Sterne</p>
        <div class="meter">
          <div class="fill" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <p>27%</p>
        <p>1 Sterne</p>
        <div class="meter">
          <div class="fill" style="width: 10.989%;"></div>
        </div>
        <p>11%</p>
        <p>2 Sterne</p>
        <div class="meter">
          <div class="fill" style="width: 32.4176%;"></div>
        </div>
        <p>32%</p>
        <p>3 Sterne</p>
        <div class="meter">
          <div class="fill" style="width: 11.5385%;"></div>
        </div>
        <p>12%</p>
        <p>4 Sterne</p>
        <div class="meter">
          <div class="fill" style="width: 17.5824%;"></div>
        </div>
        <p>18%</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a general rule of thumb for when to use outline and when to use border?

Comment: Here is an explanation That describes it clearly : Outline differs from borders! Unlike border, the outline is drawn outside the element's border, and may overlap other content. Also, the outline is NOT a part of the element's dimensions; the element's total width and height is not affected by the width of the outline. Border is part of the box model so it counts against the element's size. Outline is not part of the box model so it doesn't affect nearby elements